# Obtaining the expectation of function of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

Let $X$ follows $N(0,1)$ and let $Y=X+|X|$. Then, it is required to obtain the $E(Y^3)$.

**My approach**

The function $Y$ can be written as:

$\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<0 \\ 
2X & \text{ if }  x\geq0
\end{cases}$

My question is can I use the following expression to obtain the expectation:

$E(y^3)=E(8x^3)=\int_{0}^{\infty}8x^3f_x(x)dx$.

Instead of obtaining the density of $y$, is the above mentioned approach is correct?.

Comment: Your approach looks right for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $E(y^3)=E(8x^3)=\int_{0}^{\infty}8x^3f_x(x)dx$.

That is indeed the correct approach.

More correctly: $\displaystyle~\mathsf E(Y^3)~{=\mathsf E(8X^3~[X\geqslant 0]) \\= \int_0^\infty 8x^3 f_X(x)\mathsf d x \\= \int_0^\infty (8x^3 e^{-x^2/2}/\sqrt{2\pi})~\mathsf d x\\~~\vdots}$